# Error when passing argument through function for converting pandas dataframe of tweets into corpus files

Tags: python, pandas, function, nltk

I want to prepare my text data that is in a pandas dataframe for sentiment analysis with nltk. For that, I'm using code for a function that converts each row of a pandas dataframe into a corpus.

```
import nltk
# convert each row of the pandas dataframe of tweets into corpus files
def CreateCorpusFromDataFrame(corpusfolder,df):
    for index, r in df.iterrows():
        date=r['Date']
        tweet=r['Text']
        place=r['Place']
        fname=str(date)+'_'+'.txt'
        corpusfile=open(corpusfolder+'/'+fname,'a')
        corpusfile.write(str(tweet) +" " +str(date))
        corpusfile.close()
CreateCorpusFromDataFrame(myfolder,mydf)
```

The problem is I keep getting the message that

```
NameError: name 'myfolder' is not defined
```

Even though I have a folder called 'myfolder' in the same path directory of jupyter notebook that my code is in?

UPDATE:

I can see now that the issue was simply that I needed to pass the folder name as a string. Now that I've done that and amended my code. The problem I have now is that the contents of the text file created with the function are not being written into a corpus and the type of variable being created is a 'NoneType'.

```
import nltk
# convert each row of the pandas dataframe of tweets into corpus files
def CreateCorpusFromDataFrame(corpusfolder,df):
    for index, r in df.iterrows():
        id=r['Date']
        tweet=r['Text']
        #place=r['Place']
        #fname=str(date)+'_'+'.txt'
        fname='tweets'+'.txt'
        corpusfile=open(corpusfolder+'/'+fname,'a')
        corpusfile.write(str(tweet) +" ")
        corpusfile.close()
corpus df = CreateCorpusFromDataFrame('myfolder',mydf)
type(corpusdf)
NoneType
```

Comment: You have passed `myfolder` which is not defined in your code. Pass it as an string `CreateCorpusFromDataFrame('myfolder',mydf)`

Comment: Thank you. That worked for this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

You are passing `myfolder` as a variable to your function which you have not defined in your code and hence it raises a NameError.

#### Solution

Just replace it with `'myfolder'` [pass it as a string].

```
CreateCorpusFromDataFrame('myfolder',mydf)
```